# Faucet for filtered water that has the filter after the valve?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, filter, water-filtration

On Sunday at 4:30am our water filter canister blew apart and flooded our kitchen. It occurs to me that there would be a way to totally prevent that if the filter wasn't under pressure when the water is off.

Current plumbing:
Supply -> filter -> faucet valve -> faucet outlet

What I want:
Supply -> faucet valve -> filter -> faucet outlet

It would require a faucet with three hoses since it would have to go into the faucet, back out and back in. Not unlike how sprayer attachments work, especially ones with the sprayer that is also the primary faucet. With this kind of plumbing the filter would never be under pressure when the faucet is off so it would greatly reduce the chance of a leak in the system.

Does any such faucet exist? I did some searching and couldn't find one but I'm not quite sure what wording to use for the search and I get a lot of results that aren't even close, like faucet mounted filters (which technically fulfill the safety requirement but aren't what I want). In my search I found a faucet filter designed for an RO system that has three hoses but they are labeled as the supply, the waste and the drain so it doesn't appear to be useful to me. My filter is a simple under cabinet one with just a single inlet and outlet.

Comment: What you are looking for is something like a shower faucet for a tub, a diverter.  Kind of handy really, why use filter water for dishes/washing, you want it mainly for drinking water.  It would mean a reworking of the sink plumbing.  I think there are filters that fit on the faucet, unknown if they are good.

Comment: and you have a pressure regulator outside //????

Comment: I do not have a pressure regulator outside. I have long suspected that some work they did out in our street a couple decades ago has caused our water to be overly high pressure. I bought a small gauge to test the pressure and it wasn't crazy high (been too long to remember what it was at the moment).

Answer (score 2):

Look into excess flow valves. They are designed to shutoff flow in the event of a rupture. They automatically close when flow exceeds a pre-determined rate.
Here is one available at Home Depot.
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Water-Block-1-2-in-Automatic-Excess-Flow-Water-Shut-Off-Valve-WB-13R/306606840

Comment: That is an interesting disaster prevention option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used one of these in the past for a countertop filter system.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08P44KL6N/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08P44KL6N)

They call it a faucet diverter.  I call it a 5-way valve because it has 2 inputs and 3 outputs.